# How to use Panels to handle node url in drupal

Tags: drupal, panels, pathauto

I have a content type named `hardware` and use Pathauto module to set an alias to `hardwares/[node:nid]` .
After that, I have created a pages with handle the url `hardwares/%node`.

But looks Panels doesn't handle that url, it always render built-in node template.

I have tried to remove that url alias, and visit the `hardwares/<some id>` it will work fine. but the cannot change the node url with different content type.

So anyone could help me about that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override a node page use pages type System node_view and in Variants / Selection rules / Context you can select content type, nid or any other context

Comment: the problem is I want to custom the node url with node type, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Thats not a problem a node_view panel will override any node type that you tell it to in the selection rules and it will keep the url that you set with pathauto

Comment: I understand the drupal now, the same url but can be render with difference contents within the selection rules, really thank you.